# SQL count number of people by number of orders

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help getting a certain outcome from sql.
**users table:**

```
userid | name
-------|-----------
1      | Bob Robert
2      | Steve Smith
3      | Willard Henegar
4      | Max Rockwell
5      | Marion Paley
6      | Marcus Delisle
```

**orders table:**

```
orderid | userid
--------|-------
1       |1
2       |1
3       |1
4       |2
5       |3
6       |2
7       |4
8       |4
9       |5
10      |4
11      |4
12      |1
```

**wanted outcome**

```
numOrders | numPeople
----------|----------
0         |1
1         |2
2         |1
3         |0
4         |2
```

so basically i want to show how many people have no orders, how many people have 1 order, 2 orders, etc.

I tried to figure it out and came up with this:

```
SELECT
 Count(orders.orderid) AS numOrders,
 Count(users.userid)   AS numPeople 
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN orders 
              ON users.userid = orders.userid 
GROUP  BY numOrders
```

but this gives my an error that i can't group on numOrders.
Any suggestions on how i could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also want Users without any orders, you can do the following:

```
select NumOrders, count(*) as NumPeople
from (
    select u.UserId, count(*) as NumOrders
    from users u
    left join orders o on o.UserId = o.UserId
group by o.UserId
) t
group by t.NumOrders
```

You could also do:

```
select NumOrders, count(*) as NumPeople
from (
    select
    u.UserId, 
    (select count(*) from orders o where o.UserId = u.UserId) as NumOrders
from users u
) t
group by t.NumOrders
```

As Gordon mentioned, having a number table would help. If you know that no one will have more than say, 1,000 orders, and you want show one row for each number  0 - 1000, you could do something like this:

```
select number as NumPeople, isnull(p.NumOrders, 0) as NumOrders
from master..spt_values v
left join 
(
    select t.NumOrders, count(*) as NumPeople
    from ( select
            u.UserId, 
            (select count(*) from order o where o.UserId = u.UserId) as NumOrders
    from users u) t
    group by NumOrders
) p on p.NumOrders = v.number
where type = 'P'
and number <= 1000
```

The above would work for SQL Server. I'm not sure if MySQL has a master values table, but otherwise, you could easily create a number table and swap that out.

Answer (score 2):

You want a double histogram.  This is the easiest way:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(userid), max(userid)
from (select u.userid, count(o.userid) as cnt
      from users u left join
           orders o
           on u.userid = o.userid
      group by u.userid
     ) u
group by cnt;
```

This will not, however, give you the row with 0 count.  That requires a bit more effort.  It helps if you have a `numbers` table to fill in the missing values.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(userid), numorders 
from(
SELECT
Count(*) AS numOrders,
userid 
from orders 
group by userid ) t
group by numorders
```

`Orders` table would be sufficient as you just need the count of orders and users.